# top command till a process runs out

Tags: linux, testing, cpu-usage

I'm running a process and I want to store its CPU usage.

So I used top command

```
{ test_case.sh > out.log ; } && { sleep 2s ; x=`pidof test_case` ; top -p $x -d 5 -b > cpu.log ; }
```

But the cpu.log file is empty and out.log contains the output of test_case

I don't know why.

Can you help me to get the output of the top command till that process completes

Comment: Well ... you're making sure that top gets started **after** your process is finished.  ( `&&` ) .... so `cpu.log` being empty shouldn't come as a surprise.

Comment: Then what shall i do to run both commands paralleyly

Comment: Run the test_case.sh > out.log to the background and so add & to the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you wanted with :

```
test_case.sh > out.log & top -p $! -d 5 -b > cpu.log
```